# Golang flock filelocking throwing panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: file, go, flock, filelock, panic

I have a go program that modifies my configuration file. I am trying to create a filelock from within the main() function, but it is throwing a `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` error. Without the lock, the program is working fine as expected. The piece of code that throws exception is

```
lockProgram, err := os.Create("/var/.daemon.lock")
defer lockProgram.Close()
CheckForError(err)
GetLock(lockProgram, syscall.LOCK_EX)
defer UngetLock(lockProgram)
```

//This is in a separate package

```
func CheckForError(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        Error.Println(e)
        panic(e)
    }
}

func GetLock(file *os.File, locktype int )  {
    fmt.Println("Acquiring lock on ", file.Name())
    syscall.Flock(int(file.Fd()), locktype)
    fmt.Println("Acquired filelock on ", file.Name())
}
func UngetLock(file *os.File)  {
    syscall.Flock(int(file.Fd()), syscall.LOCK_UN);
}
```

This same `flock` is working when I call it on my configuration file, but from a different package, not main package, but throws the same error when I try to put lock from within the main package. Please help me in finding out what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You're calling defer before checking for an error. If there is an error the file will be nil.

Comment: @JimB, please correct me if I am wrong, but defer is stacked, and will be executed only when the function is about to get finished, right? Can it create a problem?

Comment: That doesn't matter. If your function ends and `lockProgram` is nil you will get a panic. You need to check the error and return early if you want to defer the close

Comment: Thank you @JimB, this helps.

Comment: When your program panics you get the stack trace. Please tell where exactly panic occurs. Is it in your CheckForError function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an error occurs while creating the lock, `lockProgram` will be `nil`. This will cause the subsequent (deferred) call to `lockProgram.Close()` to fail.

Note that when you're panicking (like in your `CheckForError` function), deferred method calls will still be executed. This is explained in detail in [this blog article](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) (emphasis mine):

> Panic is a built-in function that stops the ordinary flow of control and begins panicking. When the function F calls panic, execution of F stops, **any deferred functions in F are executed normally**, and then F returns to its caller. To the caller, F then behaves like a call to panic. The process continues up the stack until all functions in the current goroutine have returned, at which point the program crashes.

Solution: Check for errors first, and then defer the `Close()` call:

```
lockProgram, err := os.Create("/var/.daemon.lock")
CheckForError(err)
defer lockProgram.Close()
```